# CSS properties In-Place-Editor

Tags: panels

Is there a possibility to get CSS properties at the In-Place-Editor of Panels in order to define a CSS class or are just the "stylizer" meant to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Add `.panels-ipe-editing` before your css for it to only affect IPE.

eg.

```
.panels-ipe-editing .pane-title { margin: 0px; }
```

You might need to use `!important;`